# jQuery Dialog But I can't modify the CSS

Tags: jquery, css

I need to create a Model Popup, but my company is using federated css for things.  From what I understand, the jQuery UI requires a very specific CSS/HTML structure to work.  Is there another other solution that I can use with my own custom css?

I suppose I could roll my own, but wanted to get some feedback before going down that path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to modify any of your other CSS files, you just need to include the CSS file for jQuery UI which you are free to modify as you wish.

Here's another great modal window which is highly customizable:

http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/